# Minio get storage stats (used space, free space)

Tags: amazon-s3, .net-core, minio

How to get storage stats containing information about used disk space and free/available disk space. With the minio dotnet client against a Minio server?

Otherwise: how to detect storage space problems when copying files?

Comment: there is no way to check space and upload .  and such detail are available only via admin apis . you could check madmin-go - available only in Golang.